# uninitialized constant CommitsController::GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github, jrubyonrails

I am running JRuby rails. I am trying to access all the commit information (such as commit comments, committer, time of commit), given a github repositiry url for a file using mbleigh-ruby-github ruby gem. When initializing to the github namesapce, I am getting the following error: "uninitialized constant CommitsController::GitHub"

In my controller, I have the following line

```
 user = GitHub::API.user('mbleigh')
```

In gem file I have the following line

```
source 'http://gems.github.com'
gem 'mbleigh-ruby-github'
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You ran `bundle install`? What version of bundler?

Comment: yes, I ran bundle install and there were no errors. I am using bundler 1.15.0, JRuby v9.1.10.0 and rails 5.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> uninitialized constant CommitsController::GitHub

According to the [*README*](https://github.com/mbleigh/ruby-github/blob/master/README.txt) you should have `require 'ruby-github'` in your `commits_controller` which should solve the error.

```
#commits_controller.rb
require 'ruby-github'
user = GitHub::API.user('mbleigh')
```

Comment: Thanks Pavan, I now have require in commits_controller, but I get this new error message - "redirection forbidden: http://github.com/api/v1/json/mbleigh -> https://github.com/api/v1/json/mbleigh"